# Regularly background value updates work randomly

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app that needs to update a value in firebase database while the app is in the background.
I'm using silent notifications to trigger the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method. 
A push notification is received every 5 minutes.

This is my code :

```
    func updateValuesWhenNotification(input: String, completion: (result: String) -> Void) {
         refInDatabase.setValue(aValue)
         completion(result: "we finished!")
}
```

...

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {


    let aps = userInfo["aps"] as! [String: AnyObject]
    print(aps["content-available"]!)


    if (aps["content-available"]!).intValue == 1 {
        print("Content notification")
        if (loggedIn == false) {
            print("User is not logged, so no notifications")
            completionHandler(.NoData)
        } else {
            updateValuesWhenNotification("commands") {
                (result: String) in
                print("got back: \(result)")
            }
            completionHandler(.NewData)

        }


    }
```

Every time the app receive a push notification the output is :

> Content notification
>
> got back: we finished!

Means that all worked right ?

However, when the app goes into the background it **really** updates the value in the database for 2 or 3 times then stop update while the output is the same (meaning the update is triggered anyway but no real updates in the DB). And sometimes (after 20 minutes for example) it re-updates well.

What can I do/try ?
If you want me to give more precisions or indications, just ask.
Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: in the case where you are updating data (user logged in) you should call the completionHandler inside the closure, otherwise you are calling it (and indicating that you are done) before the firebase operation is complete. Also this sort of constant update isn't particularly battery or network friendly

Comment: Seems to work a lot better thank you ! Sometimes it doesn't but I will modify my cron to send push every 10 minutes instead of 5 to test.